# Python 2.7: Code won't return answer - someone explain why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code I'm using :

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    hrs=float(hours)
    rte=float(rate)
    if hrs < 40:
        pay = hrs * rte
        return pay
    else:
        pay = (rte * 40) + (hrs - 40)*(rte * 1.50)
        return pay
computepay(45,10.50)
```

If I switch the return command with print my answer shows up but the project I'm working on wants me to use return and when I run the program it isn't outputting the answer. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put a print when calling your function. For this line when you call your method:

```
computepay(45,10.50)
```

Just do this:

```
print(computepay(45,10.50))
```

You are going to print the "return" of whatever happens inside your `computepay` method.